# Why wasn't this seemingly unnecessary comment deleted?

Tags: discussion, comments, flagging

I read this comment on [Mount Everest climb cost and total time](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/65756/1810):

> If you are asking this question on a generic travel forum like this, one has to wonder if you have enough climbing experience for such an expedition. – user13044 ↵ Mar 27 '16 at 14:38

I flagged the comment as "This comment adds nothing to the question and instead is a personal attack." but my flag got denied without any reason given. Why?

Comment: How about the remark two comments down; I find that one much more snarky and delete-worthy. Look at the title of the site they link to.

Answer (score 14):

I handled that flag and I did not think that comment an personal attack.
And seeing the 47 upvotes on the comment, I would be doing a bad service to remove it on a flag which is not clear.

To tell you truth, if I had seen the question when it was newly posted, I might have posted a comment like the one we are talking about, warning the OP that there are real dangers they might not have considered.
So even without all upvotes I might have left the comment.

If your question is why was there no reason given for denying the flag? We as mods can give a reason but most of the time I do only use that option if a person repeatedly flags for the same kind of problem which I do not see as a good reason to flag.
More as a 'please stop flagging for this reason' rather than explaining why I did not delete that particular comment.

PS, Adding a reason for handling flags on comments is not possible, only for flags on questions or answers.

Comment: I completely agree.  That comment offered a very sensible reality check, not a personal attack.

Comment: I'd say it's borderline. It's an important point but as written it doesn't actually *tell* the asker anything: you need to already have the knowledge the asker lacks to know what the comment is getting at. It's more grandstanding than it is helpful. No problem leaving it since later comments explain the risk, but if the comments were mopped up, I'd replace it with something informative rather than leave it on its own.

Comment: For example, "Climbing Everest is a serious, dangerous undertaking, even for experienced mountaineers. I think you should seriously consider gaining more climbing experience, enough that you don't need to ask such a general question on a general travel site, before putting yourself and others' lives at risk".

Answer (score -4):

I agree with you that this was "too personal" comment.

But moderators agree with comment's author on the comment's meaning. For this case we know that "meta consensus" is to defend the comment.

The same would be expected with good joke. Every joke harms somebody, but would it be removed depends on moderator's sense of humor.